# Asp.net Text box Copy & Paste

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I used Asp.net Textbox and used Javascript validation (Keyboard ASCII Code) for some key restriction that works fine my need is while I copy from somewhere else paste it here I need to restrict some of the keys.
Ex - I want to restrict or disable " ) " this on while pasting.

```
function AlphaNumeric(evt)
{
    var AsciiCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (AsciiCode > 64 && AsciiCode < 91 || AsciiCode > 96 && AsciiCode < 123 || AsciiCode > 47 && AsciiCode < 58 || AsciiCode == 127 || AsciiCode == 8 || AsciiCode == 32 || AsciiCode == 45 || AsciiCode == 95)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `regx` Expression and bind it to the `Paste` event on `DOM` ready

here is the snippet [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/9z60bu56/)

**HTML**

```
<input id="textInput" name="textInput">
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#textInput").bind('paste', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //get the value of the input text
    var data = $('#textInput').val();
    //replace the special characters to '' 
    var dataFull = data.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
    //set the new value of the input text without special characters
    $('#textInput').val(dataFull);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
if(ASCII==22 && ASCII==41)
  return false;
```

Comment: How can a single object be equal to two different values at the same time?  This is literally impossible...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used this ...

```
$(function(){

    $('#txt_box').keyup(function()
    {
        var yourInput = $(this).val();
        re = /[`~!@#$%^&*()|+\=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi;
        var isSplChar = re.test(yourInput);
        if(isSplChar)
        {
            var no_spl_char = yourInput.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()|+\=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
            $(this).val(no_spl_char);
        }
    });

});
```